# WebMethod para criar Documento de Venda com edição de parametros nas linhas do documento

Tags: c#

Bom Dia,

Estamos a desenvolver um webservice / metodo que cria documentos de venda.

No cabeçalho eu consigo passar os valores todos aos parametros do cabeçalho.
Mas nas linhas como consigo fazer o mesmo?
Por exemplo, se quiser alterar a descrição do artigo, ou a taxa de iva, ou se quiser passar valores a campos do utilizador... como faço?

No exemplo seguinte não consigo....

Alguma ajuda ou sugestão? Obrigado.

```
public string SalesDocument(string sTransactionID, string sInstance, string sCompanyCode, string sUsername, string sPassword, string xml)

{
        string sNrDoc = "";
        string sResp = string.Empty;

        var Lista = new StdBELista();
        try
        {

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
            var trans = new StdBETransaccao();
            var vTipoPlataforma = new EnumTipoPlataforma();
            var DocVenda = new GcpBEDocumentoVenda();
            var CDUPrimavera = new StdBECampos();

            string sExtDocNumber = string.Empty;
            string sSONumber = string.Empty;
            string sTipoDoc = string.Empty;
            string sEntidade = string.Empty;
            string sTipoEntidade = string.Empty;
            string sSerie = string.Empty;
            string sMoeda = string.Empty;
            string sCN = string.Empty;
            string sCNOriginalDocNumber = string.Empty;
            string sCondPag = string.Empty;
            string sModoPag = string.Empty;
            string sNumberLines = string.Empty;
            string sComments = string.Empty;
            string sShippingAddress1 = string.Empty;
            string sShippingAddress2 = string.Empty;
            string sShippingCity = string.Empty;
            string sShippingPostalCode = string.Empty;
            string sShippingPostalCodeCity = string.Empty;
            string sShippingCountry = string.Empty;

            int iNrLines = 0;
            string sArtigo = string.Empty;
            string sDescricao = string.Empty;
            int sCodIva;
            double sPrecoUnit;
            double sQuantidade;
            string sUnidade;
            double sDescontoLinha;
            string sObs = string.Empty;

            string dataXML;

            DateTime dDataDoc;

            int codigoInteracao;
            string strSql = "";
            string strQuantos = "";

            StdBELista qyrConsultaCodigo = new StdBELista();

            vTipoPlataforma = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpProfissional;

            ErpBS motor = new ErpBS();
            motor = DaMotorInicializado(vTipoPlataforma, sCompanyCode, sUsername, sPassword, trans, sInstance);

            var plataforma = DaPlataformaInicializada(sCompanyCode, sUsername, sPassword, sInstance);

            strQuantos = "select count(CDU_Codigo) as Total from TDU_web_moneris";
            qyrConsultaCodigo = motor.Consulta(strQuantos);
            codigoInteracao = qyrConsultaCodigo.Valor("Total") + 1;

            XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DocHeader");

            sExtDocNumber = xnList[0]["ExternalDocNumber"].InnerXml;
            sSONumber = xnList[0]["SONumber"].InnerXml;
            sTipoDoc = xnList[0]["DocCode"].InnerXml;
            sEntidade = xnList[0]["ClientCode"].InnerXml;
            sTipoEntidade = "C";
            sSerie = xnList[0]["Serie"].InnerXml;
            dataXML = xnList[0]["Date"].InnerXml;
            dDataDoc = DateTime.Parse(dataXML);
            sMoeda = xnList[0]["Currency"].InnerXml;
            sCN = xnList[0]["CN"].InnerXml;
            sCNOriginalDocNumber = xnList[0]["CNOriginalDocNumber"].InnerXml;
            sModoPag = xnList[0]["PaymentMethod"].InnerXml;
            sCondPag = xnList[0]["PaymentTerm"].InnerXml;
            sNumberLines = xnList[0]["NumberOfLines"].InnerXml;
            sComments = xnList[0]["Comments"].InnerXml;
            sShippingAddress1 = xnList[0]["ShippingAddress1"].InnerXml;
            sShippingAddress2 = xnList[0]["ShippingAddress2"].InnerXml;
            sShippingCity = xnList[0]["ShippingCity"].InnerXml;
            sShippingPostalCode = xnList[0]["ShippingPostalCode"].InnerXml;
            sShippingPostalCodeCity = xnList[0]["ShippingPostalCodeCity"].InnerXml;
            sShippingCountry = xnList[0]["ShippingCountry"].InnerXml;

            //bool bErro = false;
           //string sIsAlive = IsAlive(sInstance, sCompanyCode, sUsername, sPassword);

            //if (sIsAlive == "000")
            //{
            //    sResp = sTransactionID;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    sResp = sTransactionID + "#" + sIsAlive;
            //    bErro = true;
            //}


            //if (motor.Comercial.Vendas.ExisteReferencia("000",sTipoDoc,sSerie,sEntidade,sExtDocNumber))
            //{
            //    bErro = true;
            //    sResp += "#200";

            //}


            CDUPrimavera.set_Item("CDU_ExternalDocNumber", sExtDocNumber);

            DocVenda.set_Referencia(sSONumber);
            DocVenda.set_Tipodoc(ref sTipoDoc);
            DocVenda.set_Entidade(ref sEntidade);
            DocVenda.set_TipoEntidade(ref sTipoEntidade);
            DocVenda.set_Serie(ref sSerie);
            DocVenda.set_DataDoc(ref dDataDoc);
            DocVenda.set_Moeda(sMoeda);

            CDUPrimavera.set_Item("CDU_CN", sCN);
            CDUPrimavera.set_Item("CDU_CNOrigDocNumber", sCNOriginalDocNumber);

            DocVenda.set_ModoPag(ref sModoPag);
            DocVenda.set_CondPag(ref sCondPag);

            motor.Comercial.Vendas.PreencheDadosRelacionados(ref DocVenda);

            CDUPrimavera.set_Item("CDU_TotalLines", sNumberLines);

            DocVenda.set_Observacoes(sComments);
            DocVenda.set_MoradaFac(sShippingAddress1);
            DocVenda.set_Morada2Fac (sShippingAddress2);
            DocVenda.set_LocalidadeFac(sShippingCity);
            DocVenda.set_CodigoPostalFac(sShippingPostalCode);
            DocVenda.set_CodigoPostalFac(sShippingPostalCodeCity);
            DocVenda.set_PaisFac(sShippingCountry);

            DocVenda.set_CamposUtil(CDUPrimavera);

            XmlNodeList xnListLinhas = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Line");
            foreach (XmlNode oNo in xnListLinhas)
            {

                sArtigo = oNo["ItemCode"].InnerXml;
                sCodIva = Int32.Parse(oNo["VatCode"].InnerXml);
                sPrecoUnit = double.Parse(oNo["UnitPrice"].InnerXml);
                sQuantidade = double.Parse(oNo["Quantity"].InnerXml);
                sUnidade = oNo["Unit"].InnerXml;
                sDescontoLinha = double.Parse(oNo["Discount"].InnerXml);

                motor.Comercial.Vendas.AdicionaLinha(DocVenda, sArtigo, sQuantidade, "", "", sPrecoUnit, sDescontoLinha, "", sQuantidade, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 0);

                //Aqui os parametros a passar são fixos, não me permite alterar a descrição ou a taxa de iva, etc....

            }
            motor.Comercial.Vendas.Actualiza(DocVenda, "", "");

            string qNumDoc = "select max(numdoc) as Ndoc from CabecDoc where TipoDoc = '" + sTipoDoc + "' and Serie = '" + sSerie + "'";

            Lista = motor.Consulta(qNumDoc);
            sNrDoc = Lista.Valor("Ndoc").ToString();
            string sDocPDF = "";
            sDocPDF = @Server.MapPath("~/Files/Documentos/") + sCompanyCode + "_" + sNrDoc + "_" + sSerie + ".pdf";

            motor.Comercial.Vendas.ImprimeDocumento(sTipoDoc, sSerie, int.Parse(sNrDoc), "000", 1, "", false, sDocPDF, 1);






            System.IO.FileStream dd = System.IO.File.OpenRead(sDocPDF);
            byte[] Bytes = new byte[dd.Length];
            dd.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);

            strSql = "Insert into TDU_web_moneris values('" + codigoInteracao + "','" + sInstance + "','" + sCompanyCode + "','" + sUsername + "','" + sPassword + "','" + xml + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + Bytes + "')";
            plataforma.ExecSql.ExecutaXMLSqlServer(strSql);





            motor.FechaEmpresaTrabalho();
            plataforma.FechaPlataforma();

            return sResp;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Logs/") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh_mm_ss") + ".txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("SalesDoc Method - Error: " + ex.Message);
                writer.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return sResp;
        }
        finally
        {


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso basta editar a última linha adicionada ao objeto `DocVenda`, ainda dentro do ciclo `foreach` (onde está a adicionar as linhas, uma-a-uma) e alterar o valor das propriedades que quiser:

```
// ...
foreach (XmlNode oNo in xnListLinhas)
{
    sArtigo = oNo["ItemCode"].InnerXml;
    sCodIva = Int32.Parse(oNo["VatCode"].InnerXml);
    sPrecoUnit = double.Parse(oNo["UnitPrice"].InnerXml);
    sQuantidade = double.Parse(oNo["Quantity"].InnerXml);
    sUnidade = oNo["Unit"].InnerXml;
    sDescontoLinha = double.Parse(oNo["Discount"].InnerXml);

    motor.Comercial.Vendas.AdicionaLinha(DocVenda, sArtigo, sQuantidade, "", "", sPrecoUnit, sDescontoLinha, "", sQuantidade, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 0);

    GcpBELinhaDocumentoVenda linhaVenda = venda.get_Linhas()[venda.get_Linhas().NumItens];

    linhaVenda.set_Descricao("teste");
    linhaVenda.set_TaxaIva(21);
    linhaVenda.get_CamposUtil().get_Item("CDU_Teste").Valor = "olá mundo!";
}
// ...
```